# Removing specific rows from my dataset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, rows

i stored few rows of my dataset in a variable based on a condition. how do i delete those specific rows from my original dataset?

eg. I stored few rows in min_price_anomalies using -

min_price_anomalies= Dataset.loc[Dataset["min_price"]>Dataset["max_price"]]

printing it gives me a few rows (about 232 row values for each column of course.)
how do I delete these specific rows from my original dataset, because I don't need them....(obviously, min_price can't be greater than max_price...)

Comment: `Dataset=Dataset[~(Dataset["min_price"]>Dataset["max_price"])]`?

Comment: @ Anurag I've not understood what you wanted to say...